# Modern hierarchical database

Tags: hierarchical-data, hierarchical, hierarchical-clustering

I'm working on the architecture of a new system to replace an ancient mainframe app. The mainframe uses IBM IMS and is surprisingly fast with large amounts of data. We've tried 3 DBs so far - MongoDB, SQL Server and Oracle, but they performed poorly under load. We hired an Oracle consultant and a 128 cores server and Oracle still gives us 4x the response time of the old system (same with SQL Server).

Are there any modern hierarchical DBs, that can efficiently support billions of records?

Comment: This is rather too broad to answer - there could be a lot of reasons for this. That said, I would expect you would get much better performance out of all of the newer systems you have tried, since internal optimisation techniques get better as time goes on. For billions of records, I suspect you'll be looking at sharding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainframes have been and remain very fast for certain use cases, so part one is not to assume that mainframe = bad.  Having said that, they can be very expensive to maintain, and particularly with legacy apps the skills are starting to evaporate.

If you really wanted a hierarchical database, one valid option would be to modernise your application but retain IMS at the core.  IMS is a great hierarchical database, and I don't think IBM are going to EOL IMS any time soon, so is there a real reason to go to a hierarchical database that *isn't IMS*? A quick visit to their website gave me the impression that they'd discount the product if they thought you were going to migrate to a competing product, so if money is the problem then perhaps the answer is to just ask IBM to discount the product you're already happy with.  This white paper (ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/ims/pdf/TCG2013015LI.pdf) suggests they're pushing that as an option, and no doubt the later versions of IMS have a bunch of features that might not be available in the version you're running (assuming you've not upgraded to the latest).

I'm surprised you can't get the performance you want out of Oracle though, the system I'm currently working on has a couple of tables at the billion mark and we definitely don't have 128 cores, but we get reasonable performance.

My first question is whether your Oracle consultant really knew their stuff. I've had mixed results, I guess like any skill set people can have variable skills.  I often find that when you get performance problems it's because people have over-normalised or over-generalised the database schema - so you've moved from a highly optimised hierarchical structure in IMS that flies to a very abstracted structure in 3NF, and that dies.  But sometimes if you put that same hierarchical structure in Oracle, and only allow the same sort of access patterns that were possible in IMS, you'd get all the performance you want.

By that, I mean if in IMS you had clients, clients had orders, and orders had order lines, then I think that means it's pretty hard to do any accesses without starting at the client.  It also often means you have large batch processes that process all the clients every day to find out which have orders that you need to do something with.

So, some things here.  Firstly, if, in Oracle, you were to build that structure - so I have a client id, the client id is the first element in the primary key of orders, and the client id then the order id are the first two elements in the primary key of order lines, and then I use client id as my clustering key and put client id into every index......probably all my client-based access paths will be really fast.  You can also partition by client id, and if needed, run an Oracle RAC cluster with each of those partitions/client ranges effectively running as separate databases on a separate more commodity class machine (say, a dual socket machine = about 20 cores).

Secondly, if I used to have to process all my records once a night to find the orders that needed someone to work on them, then in the new relational world I don't need to do that any more, I just need to find the orders with a status of "pending" or whatever.  So maybe Oracle isn't as fast for that batch oriented workload, but if I change my logic and do an indexed query for pending orders, then again I can get all the performance I want.  Even more so, perhaps I make order_status into a partitioning key, so my "active" records are all in one partition, and all the older orders are in other partitions - and then I put that partition on an SSD-backed array.

Thirdly, take a look at your storage devices.  Performance problems in databases are invariably IO problems - either you're doing too much IO (poorly optimised queries), or your IO subsystem can't keep up with the IO that you need to do.  128 cores is an awful lot of compute, and I've rarely seen a database that is compute bound.  Maybe look at a big SSD array, some of them can give you enormous IO throughput.  Certainly if you were running Oracle on a RAID 5 spinning disk array your performance is likely to suck.

The last random comment here - a lot of people are getting good results with SAP HANA - a fully in-memory database.  That really flies, and is specifically designed for workloads that just won't run fast enough in other databases.  I bet SAP would come demo it to you for free if you wanted it.